# C++ how to check a condition before using initialiser list?

Tags: c++, initializer-list

I am writing a piece of code that is structured this way:

```
//field.h
class Field {
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> data;

    public:
    Field(int, int);        
};
Field::Field (int dim0, int dim1) :: data(dim0, std::vector<double>(dim1, 0)) { }
```

Then I am using this Field in another class like:

```
//approx.h
class Field;
class Approx {
    Field SWAP;

    public:
    Approx(int, int);
};
Approx::Approx (int size, int dim) { }
/*I want to initialise SWAP like this:
     if (size > dim) SWAP(size, dim)
     else SWAP(dim, size)
*/
```

I do not know how to do this. I presume it is impossible without initialiser lists? Can I even ask inside initialiser list these questions?

If there is another way to do so, I'd be grateful for any type of solution.

Comment: Maybe write a private function `Field foo(int size, int dim)` that provides the correct result for `SWAP` depending on `size` and `dim` parameters, and use that one ini the initializer list: `Approx::Approx (int size, int dim) : SWAP(foo(size,dim))  { }`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple ways to solve this.  First, you could just use `std::min` and `std::max` to get the right values like

```
Approx::Approx (int size, int dim) : SWAP(std::max(dim, size), std::min(dim, size)) {}
```

Secondly, you could write a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) and immediately invoke it like

```
Approx::Approx (int size, int dim) : SWAP([](auto size, auto dim){ if (size > dim) return Field(size, dim); else return Field(dim, size); }(size, dim)) {}
```

If you don't like having the code in the initialization list then you can out it into a private static function and call the function instead.

Comment: Second can be simplified to `: SWAP( size > dim ? Field(size, dim) : Field(dim, size) )`

Comment: Maybe worth noting that the second statement will call move constructor instead of `(int, int)` one.

Comment: @Quimby With guaranteed copy elision no move will happen.

Comment: Honestly speaking, I don't even understand the second code. I guess I'll google a bit more about the lambda. Thanks for the help and pointing out to something new to me! :)

Comment: @Amaterastis Here is a good reference for lambda's: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

Comment: I think you forgot to pass `size`,`dim` arguments to the lambda call, but maybe capturing would be shorter?

Comment: @quimby yep, forgot that.  Fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't using std::min and max do the trick ?

```
class Field;
class Approx {
Field SWAP;

public:
Approx(int, int);
};
Approx::Approx (int size, int dim): SWAP(std::max(size,dim), std::min(size,dim))
{ }
```

Comment: Nice one! :) Pretty simple and elegant! :) Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way using delegating constructor:

```
class Approx
{
private:
    Field SWAP;

private:
    explicit Approx(std::pair<const int&, const int&> p) : SWAP(p.second, p.first) {}

public:
    Approx(int size, int dim) : Approx(std::minmax(size, dim) {}

    // ...
};
```

Answer (score -2):

You can also use `std::unique_ptr` to initialize member variables in constructor body, like:

```
class Approx {
    std::unique_ptr<Field> SWAP {nullptr};

public:
    Approx(int, int);
};

Approx::Approx (int size, int dim) {
    if (size > dim) {
        SWAP = std::make_unique<Field>(size, dim);
    } else {
        SWAP = std::make_unique<Field>(dim, size);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is wrong, because it confuses initialization and assignment. 
 Your code is poor, because you changed things that weren't wrong and gratuitously broke every single piece of code using `SWAP`.

Comment: How it confuses initialization and assignment? Its simple, you initialized member variable to nullptr, and at later point after processing input parameters to constructor you assigning correct value to member variable.

Comment: Person who asked question didnt specify whether changing `SWAP` to pointer breaks other things. We can assume he is ok with changing `SWAP.` to `SWAP->`

Comment: I honestly am not, and would agree with Ben here. If I were to change that to pointer I would have to go through 1000 of lines of code just to fix everything and it would probably take more time to do so. Still, I am grateful for the time you've spent to provide a solution. :)